# Authentication user accessibility without UI

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am developing one application which uses the youtube-data-api. I know it must be use with UI but I want to use it with predefined my own user credentials with back functionality in Curl or any php programming.

So I want like on one click my app should automatically get the auth access code without UI which is based on just a web server link calling from application back-end.

Can you please help to sort out my issue?

Comment: So what have you already tried? Check this on [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It already works like that. What you are trying to get rid of is the user selection/confirmation window from Google. Sorry, but that stays as is a requirement for security and checks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are going to have with this is that YouTube API doesn't not support service accounts.

You are going to have to use Oauth2 and authenticate your application once.  Save the refresh token then use the refresh token to access the account later from your back end application.

You will have to keep an eye on it refresh tokens don't expire often but on rare cases they can expire you will need to authenticate it again if it does.